# Javascript: empty array in inspector still has elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've stumbled across an extremely worrying problem in javascript. I have an empty array of length 0 (the elements have been spliced out), this is confirmed in the inspector. However if I assign it's length to a variable, or execute a toString on it, I get values!

This screenshot sums up the issue

[image]

Am I going mad or is this some crazy js bug I've found?

Comment: Definitely can't reproduce by just creating an empty array and calling toString on it. Can you give more context for your question? Also why are you debugging minified Javascript? Try including the unminified source in your page, and see what comes before that chunk of code that seems to be the "problem"

Comment: Regardless of whether it's minified or not the inspector still clearly shows a different object to that which is being read by the code.
I didn't include it in the screen grab, but if I create a variable and assign it to this.children.length it shows as 4 in the inspector, but, as you can see, the inspector says length is 0.

Unfortunately I haven't been able to reproduce this in a smaller example either, it appears to be some sort of perfect storm scenario in my application but it is reproducible every time.

Comment: As you said, "it seems to be some sort of perfect storm in my app that's reproducible every time" - so help others reproduce the problem! A screenshot of the problem isn't enough to reproduce the problem - give some more context, e.g. a snippet of your code calling EaselJS. Also, by showing the unminified source in your question, others can grab the unminified source and debug using it. Then again if this is more of a bug with EaselJS you should be filing that with the maintainers, not StackOverflow.

Comment: Hi again.
So you're saying you have no idea why the inspector would be reporting an object completely different to that which appears in the code?
If I can figure out an easy way to reproduce this I will post an update, but the core part of the issue: "The web inspector does not match the actual object" remains a mystery

Comment: Have you tried debugging with a different browser then? Internet Explorer's Javascript debugger is not that far behind from Chrome's.